# How to import a COVID-19 data table from a website into a Mathematica notebook

Tags: import, data, data-acquisition

This link https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ provides daily cases of COVID-19 across all the countries. Is there an easy way to retrieve this table into a Mathematica notebook?

I tried:

```
Import["https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/", "HTML"]
```

which retrieves the data in an unformatted structure.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using another source with friendlier formatting, such as the [European Centre for Disease Control and Prevention's data set](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/download-todays-data-geographic-distribution-covid-19-cases-worldwide), which is available as CSV, XLM, or JSON; or the database maintained by [Our World in Data](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data), which is explicitly freely available in various formats as well.

Comment: @MarcoB: I tried to import the data for a selected set of countries using MMA but the results are not so impressive because there are many text I am not interested in. I have a list of countries `{Turkey, USA, China}` for which I like to retrieve the data for several variables:  `{Total Cases, New Cases, Total Deaths, Total Recovered, Population}`. How can I create this table using MMA code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*( Not an answer, extended comment.)*

In this particular case (the code of that site today):

```
lsData = Import["https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus", "Data"]
```

works. Meaning, the data can be investigated further using `Cases`, `Part`, and `TableForm` (or other tabular formatting function.)

[image]

For example, this list

```
lsTbls = Cases[
   lsData, {{"#", "Country, Other", "Total Cases", "New Cases", 
     "Total Deaths", ___}, ___}, \[Infinity]];
Length[lsTbls]

(* 3 *)
```

has three elements that (seem to) correspond to "Now", "Yesterday", "2 days ago" shown in the site.

Note, the data has a continent column, but the import above did not align the rows/columns properly. Meaning, further data massaging / wrangling is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Read the data not with "HTML" but with "Data":

```
dat = Import["https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/", "Data"];
```

Now you have all data in one big mess and you need to pick it apart.

E.g.:

```
TableForm[tt[[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]], TableHeadings -> {None, tt[[2, 2, 2, 1, 1]]}]
```

Or:

```
TableForm[tt[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], TableHeadings -> {None, tt[[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]]}]
```

E.t.c.